# Table in struct initialisation in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

How to initialise the table `DetectionSensors` in this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    DetectionSensor *DetectionSensors[];
    unsigned char nbSensors;

}  SENSOR_STRUCT;

SENSOR_STRUCT my_var = { } ?
```

This table contains just some DetectionSensor pointers;

Answer (score 2):

You can't; the structure definition shown shouldn't compile.

```
typedef struct
{
    DetectionSensor *DetectionSensors[];  // Not C
    unsigned char nbSensors;
} SENSOR_STRUCT;
```

If you're trying for a flexible array member (FAM), that has to be the last field in the structure and you can't write initializers for structure containing a FAM.

Otherwise, you need to use an explicit size for the dimension of the array, or lose the array notation and use `DetectionSensor *DetectionsSensors;` (or conceivably, but it seems implausible) `DetectionSensor **DetectionSensors;`.

```
typedef struct
{
    DetectionSensor *DetectionSensors[10];  // Use an enum or #define
    unsigned char nbSensors;
} SENSOR_STRUCT;
```

With this, you need some `DetectionSensor`s around:

```
DetectionSensor ds[10];

SENSOR_STRUCT my_var = { { &ds[0], &ds[1], &ds[2], &ds[3] }, 4 };
```

In general, reserve ALL_CAPS for macros (`FILE` and `DIR` notwithstanding).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to initialise the structure with a predefined set of Detectionsensor, you can do like this.

```
DetectionSensor sample [] = {sensor1, sensor2];

my_var.DetectionSensors = sample;
```

Comment: are you sure, that there is some memory for the sensors allocated?

Comment: @JörgBeyer Well, i don't think I need that here.The variable declared in the struct is actually a pointer to pointer. And, if I have a predefined array which is declared elsewhere, I'm just doing a pointer assignment here. I can access them later as 'my_var.DetectionSensors[i]'

Answer (score 0):

You should reserve some memory for the DetectionSensors, e.g. this way:

```
#define MAX_SENSORS 10

typedef struct
{
    DetectionSensor *DetectionSensors[MAX_SENSORES];
    unsigned char nbSensors;

}  Sensor_Struct;

Sensor_Struct my_var;
myvar.DetectionSensors[0] = somePointer;
my_var.nbSensors = 1;
```

btw: CAPS_LOCKED_NAMES are by convention for preprocessor variables (`#define SOMETHING abc`)

You could provide functions to add a new sensor and even make the memory use dynamic, if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic constructor for C `struct`s, first you need to build the `DetectionSensors` array and then assign the value of that array to the DetectionSensor variable in your `SENSOR_STRUCT`.

```
typedef struct
{
    DetectionSensor * DetectionSensors;
    unsigned char nbSensors;

}  SENSOR_STRUCT;

DetectionSensor * sensors = ...; //get your detection sensors.
SENSOR_STRUCT my_var = {sensors, ... };
```